# Artefacts when drawing a scaled QImage onto a QWidget

Tags: qt, qt4

My main window has the following draw-function:

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    QImage sign(50, 50, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
    QPainter p(&sign);
    p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
    p.fillRect(sign.rect(), QColor(255, 255, 255, 0));
    p.setBrush(Qt::blue);
    p.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    p.drawEllipse(0, 0, sign.width(), sign.height());
    p.end();

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawImage(rect(), sign, sign.rect());
}
```

So basically, it draws a blue filled circle onto a QImage and than draws that QImage onto the widget. However, when I resize the window, I get weird artefacts (in the upper left corner). This is what it looks like:

original: 
[image]

after changing the window size:
[image]

Does anyone have an idea why this is?

(I'm working under Ubuntu 10.04, if that's of interest)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your `QImage` is initialized with garbage. After constructing it, call `sign.fill()`. I tried your code and the artifacts were present even before resizing on my machine.

From the Qt docs:

> QImage::QImage ( int width, int
>   height, Format format )
>
> Constructs an
>   image with the given width, height and
>   format.
>
> Warning: This will create a QImage
>   with uninitialized data. Call fill()
>   to fill the image with an appropriate
>   pixel value before drawing onto it
>   with QPainter.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick! :) I was assuming the "p.fillRect(sign.rect(), QColor(255, 255, 255, 0));" would do the "initialization", since it'd fill the complete QImage with a color. However the artifacts have gone once I inserted a "fill()"-call. I'm not sure I understand why, though. However, thank you very much for your answer! :)

Comment: I believe the problem is that p.fillRect() with the specified color and transparency is filling a rectangle with a color that is adjusted by the transparency value specified. It does not actually alter the alpha channel of the image which retains its random uninitialized values. This is just a guess though.

Answer (score 1):

Your image is transparent (except for the circle), and you never clear the window before painting the (resized) image, so artifacts from the previous circle/window size might be left over.

Before you draw the image into the window, add these lines:

```
QPalette palette = QApplication::palette();
painter.fillRect(event->rect(), palette.color(QPalette::Window));
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. :) I tried that, but it didn't actually solve the problem. But still, you are correct that the widget needs to be cleared :)